# API endpoint for a single item -- POST vs PUT

Tags: rest, http, post, put

Let's take the following API:

[image]

One of the things that I'm always a bit unclear about is when updating the `/posts/{id}` item. If a post consists of:

- ID
- Title
- Author
- PostedAt
- Body

What if we want to wipe out a previous post and update it with the new post (that is, something like `getByID.update(title, author, body)` -- would this be done via a `PUT` request or a `POST` request? Would it ever make sense to `POST` to a `/posts/{id}` or does a `POST` essentially mean it creates a new entry, whereas a `PUT` only updates an existing entry via its PK -- i.e., a `POST` is like a `INSERT` in SQL and a `PUT` is like an `UPDATE` in SQL.

Additionally, what if there is something like a List field? For example, `/posts/{id}/tags`, where tags could be something like `programming`, `c++`, `rest`. What if someone performed a `delete` operation here -- would it be deleting all the tags, or just a single tag?

Comment: Do these links answer your question? [What is the difference between POST and PUT in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/630453/113116), [What's the difference between a POST and a PUT HTTP REQUEST?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107390/113116), [What is the difference between PUT, POST and PATCH?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31089221/113116), [Use POST instead of PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43258725/113116)

Answer (score 1):

POST: creation of a new thing, where the location (ID) of the new thing will be determined by the server. The response is expected to contain a `Location` header telling the client where the object ended up (POST-redirect-GET pattern).

PUT: creation of a new thing at a client-defined location (in cases where that's allowable), or replacement of the thing at a given location (this includes "updates" where the body being sent by the client is a complete representation of the object, just as you would get from a GET).

PATCH: in-place partial-update of the thing at a given location.

Comment: thanks, could you please elaborate, maybe with an example or so (from another docs site?) of an example POST with the redirect-GET pattern, and then a PATCH?

Answer (score 0):

POST is for creation only. Use partial update with PATCH instead, or PUT if  the other fields are read-only.

Well in theory you can create a REST API with GET and POST only, but if there are better methods available, then you should use those.